# one view for each term or one view for all terms

Tags: 7, views

I have a vocabulary that contains terms and child terms, I would like to create a view to show the content of each child term.

```
Parent Term 1 > Child Term A 
              > Child Term B
Parent Term 2 > Child Term C
              > Child Term D
```

So do I have to create 4 views for child terms (A, B, C, D)? Or I can create one view that show each child term in its page? and if it one view how to define path for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define the views path like `taxonomy/term/%`. It will override all the terms path automatically.

Comment: and how to choose content from child term, contextual or relationship?

Comment: Add contextual argument of tid.